# How can I capitalize letters before a certain character? (^)

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to convert this:

```
foo^bar
ba^rfoo
oofrab
raboof^
```

To this:

```
FOObar
BArfoo
oofrab
RABOOF
```

Anything before the "^" (or another special character if it makes it easier) gets capitalized

Also, the removal of the "^" is also not required if it makes it easier.

Comment: What is the practical application and why do you list those languages/tools in the tags?  Is this an exercise for people to choose whichever language/tool they like?

Comment: It's kind of a long story of the purpose of this, but ultimately I am creating images out of words, and I am seeking a shorthand way to capitalizing things quickly. And for the different list of tools, whatever is easier for people to do. It helps me learn what tool is right for different jobs

Comment: What is with this case: `foo^bar^foo`

Comment: In my case, there's a 99.9% chance of that happening, so it's no biggie if it doesn't work properly in that scenario!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using GNU `sed` (Ubuntu's default) (thanks to pabouk for the `-r` option suggestion):

```
< inputfile sed -r 's/^(.*)\^/\U\1\E/' > out
```

Using `perl` (thanks to Oli for the shortened regex):

```
< inputfile perl -pe 's/^(.*)\^/\U\1\E/' > out
```

---

**Command #1 breakdown**:

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `stdin`
- `-r`: allows the use of extended regexes
- `> out`: redirects the content of `stdout` to `out`

**Command #2 breakdown**:

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `stdin`
- `> out`: redirects the content of `stdout` to `out`

**Regex breakdown**:

- `s`: performs a substitution
- `/`: starts the regex
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `(`: starts the first capturing group
- `.*`: matches any number of characters
- `)`: stops the first capturing group
- `\^`: matches a `^` character
- `/`: stops the regex / starts the replacement
- `\U`: starts converting to uppercase
- `\1`: replaces with the first capturing group
- `\E`: stops converting to uppercase
- `/`: stops the replacement

Comment: Hello kos, almost there, however it's doing the opposite. I am getting fooBAR instead of FOObar. `echo foo^bar | sed 's/^\(.*\)\^\(.*\)$/\1\U\2/'`

Comment: @TuxForLife Yes I confused myself a bit, check the update

Comment: @Serg Just updated, I forgot to stop the uppercase conversion

Comment: Likewise, but I just tried the new edit. Thank you kos, the explanation really helps too

Comment: Is there any way I can contact kos privately? I would like to communicate with him with something off topic

Comment: @TuxForLife You can drop to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and ping me with "@kos"

Comment: The second command is missing a command! I think you forgot a `perl`. Plus you don't need to replace the second capture with the second capture. Just don't capture it. `s/^(.*)\^/\U\1/` will do the job.

Comment: With GNU sed the second variant of the regex (extended regex) can be used with option `-r`: `sed -r 's/^(.*)\^/\U\1/'`

Comment: @Oli Thanks, indeed I missed the `perl` part, also updated / shortened based on your suggestion

Comment: What non GNU sed version support `\U`?

Comment: @cuonglm None, thanks for the comment. Updated

Answer (score 5):

Using `vim`:

```
vim -es '+g/\^/normal gUf^' +wq foo
```

- The `-es` turns on the venerable ex mode, and silences vim (mostly).
- `+` is used to provide vim commands as command-line arguments.
- `g/\^/` - run the command on all lines matching `/\^/`
- `normal` - run the rest of the command as a normal mode action.
- `gUf^` - convert to uppercase (`gU`) until `^` (`f^`). While using a range `g/.../` in this case), the cursor is placed at the start of each line before executing the command.
- Then save and quit (`wq`).

`f` looks for the first `^`, so lines with multiple `^` would have only the field converted. There's no simple motion for finding the last `^`. You can try going to the end of the line and searching backwards (`$F^`), but that would fail if `^` is the last character. So, you would need to do it in two steps:

```
vim -es '+g/\^./norm $F^gU0' '+g/\^$/norm gU$' +wq foo
```

Comment: muru, only first instance gets capitalized, e.g.,` FOO^bar^baz`

Comment: @Serg yes. That's what `f` does - move to first instance of the character.

Comment: Is there a way to make all instances capitalized ? I really like that vim writes back to that same file , so this would be ideal if it capitalized all instances

Comment: @Serg not in one pass. There's no simple motion that takes one to the last occurrence of a character (not counting plugins). You'd have to do: `vim '+g/\^./norm $F^gU0' '+g/\^$/norm gU$' +wq foo` - the first command for lines that don't end in `^`, and the second command for lines that end in `^`.

Comment: That works ! Can you add that to your answer ? I'll upvote

Comment: @Serg updated it.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

So after about hour and half , I came up with this:

```
awk -F' ' '{ gsub(/\^/,"@ "); for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~ /\@/) $i = toupper($i);};gsub("@ ","");gsub("@",""); print   }  ' removecharsfile
```

Basic ideas:

- get rid of ^ and replace it with @ plus space
- Treat space as field delimiter; now we have fields to play with
- for loop to step through each field in each line, and check if there is @ character.
- if there is @ character, convert that field to upper. Why $i = toupper($i) ? Because otherwise it doesn't get stored anywhere
- after the loop is done, get rid of @+space, and any @ at the end of fields.
- print everything

Perhaps better approach to writing all this on one line is to put it in a file ( neatly organized bellow ), and run that with awk like so `awk -f awkscript theinputfile`

```
# awk script to capitalize
# whatever comes before caret(^)


{
  gsub (/\^/, "@ ");
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    {
      if ($i ~ /\@/)
        $i = toupper ($i);
    };
  gsub ("@ ", "");
  gsub ("@", "");
  print

}
```

And here it is in action:

[image]

**ORIGINAL POST**

I'll contribute my own code version with awk:

`awk -F'^' '{print toupper($1)$2}' thefile`

And of course you can redirect output with `> output.txt`
And here it is in action:

[image]

Comment: Nice, but it will break with more than 2 fields: `echo foo^bar^test | awk -F'^' '{print toupper($1)$2}'` outputs `FOObar`

Comment: If you take of the last "^" after "raboof", then raboof still gets capitalized

Comment: Not sure if that's important tough, @TuxForLife is it fine to always expect 2 fields?

Comment: Sometimes a "^" won't be provided on a line, so nothing should happen in that case. But that's my own fault for not providing that in my example!

Comment: @TuxForLife I'm gonna try to improve the answer to include no "^" case

Comment: @Serg Drop me a comment when you've done, so I can give an upvote

Comment: @kos  Done. Spend some time on it but that was fun

Comment: @TuxForLife take a look at the improved version

Comment: Then +1, as promised

Comment: Note that if awk is `mawk` (the default), non-ascii letters will not be uppercased. `gawk` supports this, though, so if you install `gawk` it will handle such letters. Check which awk you have with `awk -W version`. (If you're still at mawk, I recommend installing gawk, since the mawk is 19 years old, and not POSIX-compliant)

Comment: I'm surprised the sed version is much simpler and shorter, especially since I've heard awk can handle more advanced things easier. +1, thanks for an awk alternative.  @geirha I do have gawk installed, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @TuxForLife Well, I'm pretty sure there's other guys who can do what I did with awk in a much simpler and concise way; I am merely a self-taught Ubuntu enthusiast and I learn as I go. awk is very powerful for processing texts though - I've been reading up on 'Awk Programming language' book by the creators of awk, and it's quite interesting. For instance, there's a program to convert numbers to words, like when you write a check. It's something I had to do in java with like 300 lines of code, can be done in awk with just less than 100

Comment: @geirha I've whatever came with ubuntu by default or whatever has been updated. `awk -W version` reports, GNU awk 4.0.1

Comment: @Serg, well it doesn't take much to get gawk installed. For instance, gcc depend on gawk, and quite a lot of other packages too (`apt-cache rdepends gawk`), since mawk 1.3.3 is rather useless for many things. And gawk automatically overrides the /usr/bin/awk symlink when it gets installed. I don't quite understand why Ubuntu bothers keeping mawk 1.3.3 from 1996 as the default awk, really. Should either upgrade to a recent version of mawk or switch to gawk.

Comment: @geirha I think they keep it for comparability. And here's output of `ls /usr/bin/*awk` : `/usr/bin/awk@    /usr/bin/gawk*   /usr/bin/mawk*  /usr/bin/pgawk*
/usr/bin/dgawk*  /usr/bin/igawk*  /usr/bin/nawk@`
. And yes, mawk is 1.3.3 on my system.

Comment: @Serg I believe the "program to convert numbers to words" may be very useful for me, may you please direct me to the awk version of that? Thank you Serg

Comment: @TuxForLife like I said , it is in the Kerningan's book. I'll try to find a copy of it online - surely enough somebody posted it. If I don't find it, I'll just copy it from the boot to pastebin and link it here or ping you in the chat

Comment: Thank you Serg. I am really glad you mentioned this, since my project would be better off with words rather than numbers. I found the java code you were speaking of, and it looks impressive.

Comment: @TuxForLife so I have found the book, [here](http://www.4shared.com/office/msI-5lU0ba/The_AWK_Programming_Language.htm), downloaded copy for myself,too. The algorithm is on page 74 - 75 of the text. Hope you will find it useful =)

Comment: Great Serg, I got a hold of it, I appreciate you coming back to provide me the link. 
I transcribed it since it I wasn't able to easily copy and paste it, I think I have it exact. Shoot me your email address on (on a chat?) and I'll send it to you!

Comment: @TuxForLife Send a mail just now. My email domain is @ qq.com , with number. Double check if it didn't go to spam folder automatically

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Upvoting because I feel your pain.

Answer (score 3):

I would set `^` as field separator in `awk` in upper case the first field:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="^"; OFS=""} NF>1{$1=toupper($1)}1' file
FOObar
BArfoo
oofrab
RABOOF
```

By saying `OFS=""` we set the output field separator to the empty string, so that the `^` is removed. If this is not needed, `awk -F"^" '{$1=toupper($1)}1' file` alone would make it; it converts all `^` into spaces.

Note we use `NF>1` in order to perform the upper case in case there is at least one `^`.

Comment: see, you are doing same mistakes I've done in the original post. This will works with two fields, but what if file contains something like `foo^bar^baz` ? only field $1 gets capitalized. Also text entries with no ^ still get capitalized.

Comment: @Serg you are right regarding capitalizing everything if no `^` is present. I just fiexed it, thanks. Regarding multiple ones, I understand the question as "upper case up to the first one".

Comment: OP said "Anything before the "^"", but he did not specify how many fields there are supposed to be, so you have to consider multiple possibilities. Don't get me wrong - I'm just trying to help you consider the problem from different angle

Comment: @Serg yep, I know and I appreciate it. But this wouldn't be that complicated either, you just need to loop: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="^"; OFS=""} NF>1{for (i=0;i<NF;i++) $i=toupper($i)}1' file`.

Comment: @Serg by the way, from the comments in your answer I see you are learning awk by yourself. This [idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) helped me a lot a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

Bash can also do this, so I'll throw a bash answer into the mix.

```bsh
#bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line = *^* ]]; then
        tmp=${line%%^*} 
        line=${tmp^^}${line#*^}
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < inputfile > outptufile
```

This is just iterating the inputfile line-by-line ([BashFAQ 1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)), and using parameter expansions to do the splitting and uppercasing ([BashFAQ 73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073)).

Answer (score 2):

Through python3,

Without using `re` module,

```py
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if '^' in line:
            m = line.strip().split('^')
            print(m[0].upper() + m[1])
        else:
            print(line, end="")
```

With using `re` module.

```py
import re
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(r'(.*)\^', lambda m: m.group(1).upper(), line.strip()))
```

Replace `file` in the above scripts with the actual file path. And run the script using `python3` command.

Answer (score 1):

An other `awk` version:

```
awk '{ a=$_; ismatch=sub(/\^.*/, "", a); b=gensub(/.*\^(.*)/, "\\1", "", $_); if(ismatch==1) { print toupper(a) b} else { print b} }' testdata
```

human readable ;)

```
awk '{
  a=$_;
  ismatch=sub(/\^.*/, "", a);
  b=gensub(/.*\^(.*)/, "\\1", "", $_);
  if(ismatch==1) {
    print toupper(a) b
  }
  else {
     print b
  }
}' testdata
```

Comment: For me entries with multiple ^ , like `foo^bar^baz`, get middle part removed and get only last one left - i.e., `FOObaz`

Comment: @Serg Hmmm you're right. I will change this tomorrow.

Comment: Ping me when you do, alright ?

Answer (score 1):

Another `python` approach:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '^' in line:
            index = line.find('^')
            print line[:index].upper() + line[index+1:].rstrip()
        else:
            print line.rstrip()
```

**Output :**

```
FOObar
BArfoo
oofrab
RABOOF
```

- `index = line.find('^')` contains the index of the character `^`
- `line[:index].upper()` prints the characters before `index` (`^`) in uppercase (`upper()`)
- `line[index+1:]` prints the characters after `^` literally
- `rstrip()` will remove the trailing newlines added by `print` by default.

**EDIT :**

Now if you have a file like this (multiple `^`) :

```
foo^bar^spam
ba^rfoo^egg
oofrab
raboof^spamegg
```

and you want to make it like:

```
FOOBARspam
BARFOOegg
oofrab
RABOOFspamegg
```

In this case you can use:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '^' in line:
            index = line.rfind('^')
            print line[:index].upper().replace('^', '') + line[index+1:].rstrip()
        else:
            print line.rstrip()
```

**Output :**

```
FOOBARspam
BARFOOegg
oofrab
RABOOFspamegg
```

Only replacements are `rfind('^')` instead of `find('^')`, which will find the index of rightmost `^` and `replace('^', '')` will replace all `^`s with blanks.