# How can I capitalise letters after a certain character

Tags: command-line, text-processing

[How can I capitalize letters before a certain character? (^)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622142/how-can-i-capitalize-letters-before-a-certain-character)

I am trying to do the reverse of the above link.

I want to capitalise everything after a certain character or word.

It can be using awk, sed or bash

example

before

```
 foo^bar
 foobar ^ foobar
```

after

```
 foo^BAR
 foobar ^ FOOBAR
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed 's/\^.*/\U&/' file
```

(`^` is escaped, to remove its special meaning as the start-of-line anchor; you could also use `[^]`)

or awk

```
awk -F^ 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {x=$1; $0=toupper($0); $1=x} 1' file
```

(store the first `^`-separated field; change the whole line to upper case; then replace the original first field).

Comment: Much apprecited, I have been trying all day to get this right.

Answer (score 1):

With plain bash, we need a couple of extra variables:

```bsh
for line in 'foo^bar' 'foobar ^ foobar' 'a^b^c'; do
  prefix=${line%%^*}
  suffix=${line#*^}
  caps="${prefix}^${suffix^^}"
  printf '%s ==> %s\n' "$line" "$caps"
done
```

```
foo^bar ==> foo^BAR
foobar ^ foobar ==> foobar ^ FOOBAR
a^b^c ==> a^B^C
```

- `${var%%pattern}` -> remove from the end the longest substring matching the pattern
- `${var#pattern}` -> remove from the beginning the shortest substring matching the pattern
- `${var^^}` -> capitalize

Ref: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)